# How to call a method from another class in a button click event?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, class, methods

I'm trying to call a non-static method (LoadingListBox) in my class (ListDisplay) from a button click event in my AddTask class.

```
namespace Project
{
    public partial class ListDisplay : Form
    {

        public  void LoadingListBox()
        {
            //code
        }
    }
 }

namespace Project
{
    public partial class AddTask : Form
    {
         private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             //code
             //I want to call LoadingListBox here
         }
    }
}
```

I have tried creating an instance of `ListDisplay` by doing `ListDisplay listDisplayI = new ListDisplay();` and then writing `ListDisplay.LoadingListBox();`

There were no errors with this code but when debugging the flow of control wouldn't go to the method it just carried on past it. 
I have also tried doing what the answer suggests from this question:

[Call a public method of main class from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15571164/3187637)

But that comes up with an error as I can't overload the btnSubmit_Click method as the Designer freaked out. So I created a new method that had all of the code of btnSubmit_Click called `public static void addingTask(ListDisplay)` but I then had to create an instance of ListDisplay in order to put it as an argument in the btnSubmit_Click method hence ending up with two instances which is not what I want (due to answer of question).

So now I have come up with nothing and would appreciate any help you could give in order to call this LoadingListBox method. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two choices are based on whether or not you want a new instance of `ListDisplay` when you click the button or not.

Option 1:

```
namespace Project
{
    public partial class AddTask : Form
    {
        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ld = new ListDisplay();
            ld.Show();
            ld.LoadingListBox();
        }
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
namespace Project
{
    public partial class AddTask : Form
    {
        private ListDisplay _ld;
        public AddTask(ListDisplay ld)
        {
            _ld = ld;
        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _ld.LoadingListBox();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, with option 2 how would I call AddTask as I've tried putting `AddTask AddTaskI = new AddTask(this);` and  `AddTask AddTaskI = new AddTask(ListDisplay);` and they haven't worked?

Comment: @EmmaD - What is `this` in the `new AddTask(this)`? Is it an instance of `ListDisplay`? Also, on SO, please never say "they haven't worked" without explaining what went wrong.

Comment: Don't worry I must have typed it wrong before as using `new AddTask(this)` now works! `this` being the instance of ListDisplay as I am calling it from the ListDisplay form.